# Is there any way to retrain a SPARK?

Tags: xcom-2

In XCOM 2, human soldiers can retrain their skills in the Advanced Warfare Centre. Is there anyway to retrain a SPARK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/4qxa4a/psa_sparks_can_be_respecced_in_the_awc/), SPARKs can be retrained in the AWC just like any other soldier. Unless they are currently being repaired; which means they are considered not operational.

I can confirm this works; I've retrained my SPARK in the past.

However, it's possible that a mod you have installed is causing an issue here. It wouldn't be the first time something like this has happened.

I've never encountered the issue though. Although I've only retrained a SPARK once.

Comment: Huh. I guess I never actually tried that! Or perhaps I rarely have my one SPARK un-wounded... (because it's not a big deal with the SPARKs, especially once they have the repair skill and can get themselves to full health on the first round of the battle...)